# Getting 1004 error when setting a cell formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a macro that has to insert a new row each time a button is clicked.
The thing is that some columns must have a formula in them, this one for example:

```
rating = "=IF(OR(ISBLANK($K$" & lastRow & ");ISBLANK($N$" & lastRow & ")); 0; $K$" & lastRow & "*VLOOKUP($N$" & lastRow & "; Parameter!$M$12:$N$16; 2))"
    .Cells(lastRow, 15).Formula = rating
```

I have tried to set the formula using `.Range("O" & lastRow).Formula = rating`, but it doesn't work anyhow.
Any ideas about how to fix it?

Comment: changing `;` to `,` does not help?

Comment: Actually, putting ',' instead of ';' retrieves an error. The weirdest thing in this issue is that, when I take the value gotten after the execution of this line (I mean the entire string) and I write it inside the cell as assigning the formula manually, it works, but when I try to do it programmatically it fails :(

Comment: Sorry, i have tried it as you told me and now it works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **.Formula** or **.FormulaArray**, you must use the default US-EN Office standard to set your formulas, which means using commas and English function names. If you want to use semi-colons in your code instead because you are for example using Excel in French or any other language where the commas are actually used in the numbers notation (ie. 1.5 vs 1,5), you would have to use **.FormulaLocal** with the function names written in your local language too.

With that said, please note that using `FormulaLocal` has the disadvantage of making your code irrevelant if Excel isn't using the same regional parameters as you are, which isn't a problem with `Formula` or `FormulaArray` since Excel does the conversion automatically.